# PyQt5: Change layout for multiple objects at once

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Okay, so I have a QMainWindow object that is my window and that contains several QLineEdit objects. Depending on a condition, a single QLineEdit object can change it's color (color: red if error). I'm trying to find a way to reset the color of **all** QLineEdit objects back to black (default) when pressing a button. Right now, I have them all in a single list and iterate through them, which is inefficient because I have ~60 QLineEdit objects.

I'm looking for a way to change the stylesheet globally for all QLineEdit objects within my window, at once.

Ui_MainWindow is a class that is automatically generated by Qt Designer and imported. I make all the changes to my class MainWindow, instead of Ui_MainWindow, as Qt Desginer tells me to.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow    
from Windows.main_window import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Input validation
        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.validate(self.ui.lineEdit))
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.validate(self.ui.lineEdit_2))
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.validate(self.ui.lineEdit_3))

        # Open file button
        self.ui.pushButton_Open.clicked.connect(self.open_file_dialog)

        self.show()

    # If text meets a condition, paint it red
    def validate(self, element):
        if element.text() == 'foo':
            element.setStyleSheet('color: rgb(255,0,0)')

    def open_file_dialog(self):
       self.reset_stylesheet()
       ...

    def reset_stylesheet(self):
        ui_elements = [self.ui.lineEdit, self.ui.lineEdit_2, self.ui.lineEdit_3]
        for element in ui_elements:
            element.setStyleSheet('color: rgb(0,0,0)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this but I'm not sure how much faster it will be.

I changed the connect methods to `line.textChanged.connect(self.validate)` though you could change them back use `element.setProperty` in the `validate` funciton

Add the top two lines to the `__init__` method.

```
    self.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit[validated=true]{color: rgb(255,0,0)}')
    self.lineEdits = (x for x in self.centralWidget().children()
                      if isinstance(x, QLineEdit))

# If text meets a condition, paint it red
def validate(self, element):
    if element == 'foo':
        self.sender().setProperty('validated',True)
    else:
        self.sender().setProperty('validated',False)
    self.sender().setStyle(self.style())

def invalidate(self, element):
    element.setProperty('validated', False)
    element.setStyle(element.style())
    return element


def open_file_dialog(self):
   self.reset_stylesheet()


def reset_stylesheet(self):
    tuple(map(self.invalidate, self.lineEdits))
```

Or you could just add

`self.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit{color:#FFF};')` in the `reset_stylesheet()` function

and

`self.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit{color:#F00};')` in the validate section.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution (which should work, based on the code). However, for me, my code crashes with the following error: `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'`. I'll look into fixing this, but your solution should work.

Aside form that, I never knew about self.sender(), this is amazing and will make my code a LOT cleaner. Thanks for this. – Mark Osipov 11 mins ago     Delete

Comment: After a small modification, your code worked flawlessly! Thanks for the help. I'm marking this as the answer.

Modification: instead of your proposed solution for self.lineEdits, I went with this:
`lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)`